# Httponly Cookie is deleted on browser restart

Tags: php, httpcookie

maybe I'm having a small blackout right now, but I don't understand why a httponly cookie, set by php, is deleted on browser restart?

For example I do:

```
$time = time()+2592000;
setcookie("test_cookie","test_value",$time,"","",false,true);
```

The cookie is set and expires in 30 days. When I close the browser and the php session id is renewed the cookie is deleted. Is this the desired behaviour of a httponly cookie?

Thanks, folks

Comment: are you using incognito tab?

Comment: no, "normal" firefox.

Comment: I can't spot anything blatantly wrong. How does the cookie look like in the browser developer tools? Do you have any ad blocker or tracking-protection add-on?

Comment: what you see in **View Page Information** on Contextual menu of web page

Comment: Why are you not setting the cookie as secure? This is a basic, you should be doing this. Is your PHP localhost only?

Comment: Try actually specifying the path and the domain values; blank values may be interpreted by the browser as not worth retaining(?)

Comment: Yes, I'm doing "not secure" because I test on localhost. 

I tried it on a different mashine and It works. It must be a configuration failure in my test evironment.